# On NEAR, how to delete all keys other than the FullAccess key that my Ledger seed phrase created

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to delete all keys other than the FullAccess key that my Ledger seed phrase created.

When I check which keys are associated with my NEAR Ledger account, I see some like:

```
"access_key": {
      "nonce": "aaaaaaaa",
      "permission": {
        "FunctionCall": {
          "allowance": "0",
          "method_names": [
            "__wallet__metadata"
          ],
          "receiver_id": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      }
    },
    "public_key": "ed25519:cccccccccccccc"
}
```

(fake values above)

I tried:

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near delete-key bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc --useLedgerKey
Make sure to connect your Ledger and open NEAR app
Deleting key cccccccccccccc on bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
An error occured
DisconnectedDeviceDuringOperation: Cannot write to hid device
    at new CustomErrorClass
```

What should I have done instead?

Also, note that someone should fix "occured" to "occurred".

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. The error message (with the typo) is coming from ledger, and it looks like some connectivity issue between ledger and your machine, probably not NEAR related. There is a known issue when using Ledger+node.js+NVM (see here: https://docs.near.org/tools/near-cli#mac-and-linux) maybe this can help?

Comment: @Max Hi Max! Thanks for your response. I'm on Linux rather than Mac OS X so figured there wouldn't be a problem. Are you saying that the command I ran is the right one (that `--useLedgerKey` will work with `delete-key`)? If that's the case, then it sounds like I should try again using a different USB port. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may have been an issue with USB connectivity.

The command in this syntax:

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near delete-key bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc --useLedgerKey
```

did indeed work when the Ledger was plugged directly into my laptop (rather than into a USB switch connected to my laptop) and was logged in with its NEAR app open.

Oddly, it made me confirm the public key of its FullAccess key 3 times before   then also (unsurprisingly) making me confirm the deletion of the cccccccccccccc key.

But it worked!

Now when I run `NEAR_ENV=mainnet near keys bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`, I see just the FullAccess key, so I've achieved my goal.

(Note that in my question and in this answer, I've replaced real values with fake ones.)

UPDATE:

Actually, when running `NEAR_ENV=mainnet near send xxxxxxx yyyyy 1 --useLedgerKey`, even when plugged directly into my laptop, I got this error:

```
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
An error occured
Error
    at new TransportError ...
```

But then I ran it again, and it worked, although it again weirdly  made me confirm the public key of its FullAccess key 3 times before   then also (unsurprisingly) making me confirm the transfer. So I don't know what the root cause of either issue was, but trying multiple times seems to have been an effective enough workaround.